# Mock multiple methods in Rspec where the first method takes arguments

Tags: rspec

I have a class that makes a command call to another object and I'm trying to test this in RSpec.

`SendWithUsInviteeMailer.send_invite(invitee_id).deliver`

I'd like to write something like this:

`expect(SendWithUsInviteeMailer).to receive_message_chain(:send_invite, :deliver).with(invitee.id)`

where the invitee.id is sent as an argument to the first method. How do I test this correctly? Is there a way to using message chain?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably stub the `send_invite` method and check for deliveries, like so:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

And in your spec:

```
before do
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  allow(SendWithUsInviteeMailer).to receive(:send_invite).and_call_original
end

it 'sends out the right email'
  expect(SendWithUsInviteeMailer).to receive(:send_invite).with(invitee.id)
  # perform the action to be tested
  expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq 1
end
```

Comment: Is the SendWithUs mailer a kind of action mailer? What is going on in the test setup? This probably has something to do with me not understanding actionmailer? what does it do?